# How to use "^|^|^|" in a powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have the following command to invoke:

```
ConEmu64.exe -runlist cmd -new_console:a ^|^|^| cmd.exe /k dir ^|^|^| cmd -new_console
```

When using **cmd** it works perfectly fine, but when using **powershell** I got this:

```
^ : The term '^' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fi
le, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inclu
ded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:74
+ ... onEmuPack.160707\ConEmu64.exe -runlist cmd -new_console:a ^|^|^| cmd. ...
+                                                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (^:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I bypassed it by running:

```
cmd.exe /k "ConEmu64.exe -runlist cmd -new_console:a ^|^|^| cmd.exe /k dir ^|^|^| cmd -new_console"
```

But is it possible to invoke it natively in powershell?

Comment: `ConEmu64.exe -runlist cmd -new_console:a '|||' cmd.exe /k dir '|||' cmd -new_console` or ``ConEmu64.exe -runlist cmd -new_console:a `|`|`| cmd.exe /k dir `|`|`| cmd -new_console``

Comment: Oh my god, It works! I've been trying to solve this for hours. You rock dude!